# Making the Hangeul button NOT open the menu on browsers

Tags: korean

So I've got my Korean language setup going strong and the language switching button on my keyboard is working MOST of the time - but I'm running into 2 problems. The first is the priority:

1. When I click on the language switching button to the right of the space bar - the "HangulMode" button according to https://keyboardtestt.com - then it opens the Browser menu on both Firefox and Chromium (actually Vivaldi in this case). Anyone know how to make it stop doing that?
2. Frequently when I make a capital letter - shift plus any letter - it will randomly switch to Korean. All of the sudden I'm typing in Korean when I never hit the language switching key. Sometimes it happens with the letter I, and other times it doesn't. Wish I could give you a rule for when it happens, but I haven't figured that one out yet.

Community, thank you in advance!

Comment: Here's a video that shows the problem I'm experiencing and how challenging it is to switch languages with the "HangulMode" button ~

https://video.intcultcom.com/recordings/PuLpDFMD0bJqYve1IyFE?uploadId=IHZqGNf5oIEqBYvvZTbB